# Why G-d regretted creation of the Man single?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit, adam

> וַיֹּאמֶר ה"א לֹא־טוֹב הֱיוֹת הָאָדָם לְבַדּוֹ אֶעֱשֶׂהּ־לּוֹ עֵזֶר כְּנֶגְדּוֹ׃
>
> God said, “It is not good for man to be alone; I will make a fitting helper for him.” [Bereishis 2, 18](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.2.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Nikkud&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)

As we can see up to this point Adam didn't do anything to cause such a negative judgment and only G-d was the one running the whole show up until now.

Why would G-d call His own creation/situation "לא טוב", contrary to what He states previously that everything was "טוב מאד"?

Answer (score 2):

Commentaries from [here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/2/18#e1n6).

Rav Sa'adyah Gaon notes that there was value to having Adam originally alone, and once that reached a certain point, it was better for him to have an Ezer Kenegdo. In his opinion, lo Tov means that it could be better at this point, but that originally Adam's creation was good. He lists them in his commentary, linked above.

> לא טוב היות האדם לבדו. ואין כוונתו לאמור שבהיות האדם לבדו אין טובה כלל שהלא בראו יחידי, ואין השכל נותן שברא דבר המשולל כל טוב, אלא היותו יחידי בראשונה היתה לטובתו מכמה בחינות:‏

Chizkuni seems to understand that G-d originally created Adam with the intention of also creating an Ezer Kenegdo, but that it only happened now. Therefore, we can say that it was called good before, since "stage 1" of the two-step operation was complete, but that it was still not finished.

> לא טוב היות האדם לבדו – מתחילה עלה בדעת{ו} לעשות לו זוג, ולא מצא פתח לעשות עד לאחר קריאת השמות, כדי שיתאוה לה ויחבבנה יותר.

This is similarly expressed by Shadal:

> לא טוב היות האדם לבדו – אין הכוונה לומר שהאל נמלך ממחשבתו, אלא המכוון הוא להעיר אותנו על יקרת הזווג, ולהודיע כי לא טוב היות האדם לבדו, ולפיכך רצה הקב״ה שיהיה האדם שרוי שעה אחת בלא אשה ואח״כ הזמינה לו כדי שתהיה חביבה עליו אחר שהרגיש כי בזולתה היה חסר, ומזה ילמדו גם הדורות הבאים כי לא טוב היות האדם לבדו. ותלמידי מוהר״ר איגל מוסיף כי מה שכתוב לא טוב וגו׳ אינו אלא כאומר שעדיין לא נשלמה כוונת הבורא בבריאת האדם, כי אחר בריאת כל דבר כתוב וירא אלהים כי טוב, שנעשה רצונו, וכאן לא נעשה עדיין רצונו, כי מעולם לא היה רצונו שיהיה האדם יחידי.

Rav Hirsch suggests that this took place prior to the creation of man altogether:

> ויאמר ה׳ אלקים – לפני בריאת האדם

This is similarly expressed by Rav DZ Hoffman:

> משום כך נברא האדם תחילה לבדו, כדי שירגיש את הצורך בעזר זה. ומשום כך אומר האלהים ״לא טוב״, כלומר אין הבריאה שלמה עדיין (רק אחרי השלמת הבריאה אומר ״והנה טוב מאד״).

This is also the approach of very many Rishonim who understand this to have taken place earlier (meaning, this is a detailed retelling of the creation of Adam), and therefore write that God never called Adam "Tov" before Chava was created, see Rabbeinu Bachya for example:

> הזכיר עד עתה בכל אחד מהם כי טוב לפי שהטוב הוא הקיום בכל המינין אבל בבריאת אדם שאין המין יכול להתקיים בו לבדו אמר לא טוב.